# strange behavior of POSIX date-times

Tags: r, date, posix, posixct

This behavior of POSIX objects baffles me. I make two POSIX date-time vectors, one POSIXct and other POSIXlt, that have the same dates and times. They are identical by `==` but not by `%in%` as seen in the following.

```
d.ch = c("2016-09-26 0:00:00", "2016-09-26 1:00:00", "2016-09-26 2:00:00", "2016-09-26 3:00:00", "2016-09-26 4:00:00")
d1 = strptime(d.ch, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # POSIXlt
d3 = seq(from=ISOdatetime(2016,9,26,0,0,0), 
     length.out=5, by="hour") # POSIXct
d1 == d3
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

but

```
d1 %in% d3
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Why?

Comment: `d1` appears to be POSIXlt, and d3 appears to be POSIXct. Probably `==` is doing some implicit coercion.

Comment: Have a look at `attributes(d1)` and `attributes(d3)`.  The `POSIXlt` class has more in common with a list than it does with a vector.  In fact, my understanding is that's what the `l` in POSIXlt` represents, whereas the `c` in `POSIXct` is a reference to the `c` function for making vectors. (I'm sure there's a more technical explanation)

Comment: You might investigate `lubridate` as an alternative. It makes a lot of date/time objects consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all works if you just convert the `strptime()` result to `POSIXct`.

Or if you use `anytime()` which creates `POSIXct` by default too:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> d1 <- anytime(c("2016-09-26 00:00:00", "2016-09-26 01:00:00", 
+  "2016-09-26 02:00:00", "2016-09-26 03:00:00", "2016-09-26 04:00:00"))
R> d1
[1] "2016-09-26 00:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 01:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 02:00:00 CDT" 
[4] "2016-09-26 03:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 04:00:00 CDT"
R> d3 <- seq(from=ISOdatetime(2016,9,26,0,0,0), length.out=5, by="hour") # POSIXct
R> d3
[1] "2016-09-26 00:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 01:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 02:00:00 CDT" 
[4] "2016-09-26 03:00:00 CDT" "2016-09-26 04:00:00 CDT"
R> d1 == d3
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
R> d1 %in% d3
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
R>
```

Because `anytime()` iterates over a set pre-coded formats, I had to add a zero to your hour format to make it like a regular ISOtime format.

(Oh, and CDT happens to be my timezone.)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `anytime` which works out great. But this seems to be telling me that POSIXlt and POSIXct are not really compatible, which is a travesty.

Comment: No, that is not a good way to look at it -- read `help(DateTimeClasses)`.  I think of `POSIXlt` as a _list type_ giving me access to the components, and `POSIXct` as _compact type_ suitable for single columns in data.frames or xts indices etc.  They are _different representations of the same underlying information_ but because they are _different by design_ you cannot do what you attempted in your question.

Comment: I just posted another question on SO seeking guidance on when to use which datetime type. Can you please elaborate on the semantics of POSIX.

Comment: You haven't even accepted this one, and now expect me to "hop" on demand to another one?

Comment: Oh, and I had seen that other one, and was one of the people closing it.  Your premise was wrong and _I need to re-iterate my recommendation to go and read `help(DateTimeClasses)`_.   R is really good an that, and while the documentation may be dense it will pay you back with interest.

Answer (score 2):

Both `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` inherit from the virtual `POSIXt` class. That is what allows binary operators like `==`, `+`, `-`, etc to work when one object is `POSIXct` and the other is `POSIXlt`. Those binary functions look at the class of their arguments.

`%in%` calls `match`, which does a lookup of a value from a table. There's no S3 method dispatch to take advantage of the `POSIXt` virtual class, so you get a vector of `FALSE`.

Comment: Any plan to add S3 methods to make `match` work on `POSIXt` class?

Comment: Ask R-core. Only they would know.